Session time out within 5 minutes .Net mvc 4.8
I have a application in mvc 4.8 and its session timing out within 5 minutes on iis deployed one and on locally it does not timeout and do not redirect to the login page although I added the session timeout in Session_start method with long timeout..
Global.asax.cs
    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        // ASP.NET will create a new session for every request unless you store something in it
        Session["Dummy"] = 1;
        Session.Timeout = 525600;
    }

web.config
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="525600"></sessionState>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>

application is deployed in iis shared server...
locally it does not session out tried multiple times but on deployed server it gets timeout with in 5 minutes redirect to the login..
login method contains
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, password, true, shouldLockout: false);

It was on iis server idle timeout which was set to 5 minutes changing that to larger value solved the issue..
